# Tools to make buffer around the polygon on a web map?

Tags: geoserver, postgresql, web-mapping

We're starting web map app and still deciding what tools is the best to use. We would need option that user add some points and polygons, and also, to automatically get buffer around those polygons. We considered Geoserver as the best solution, also Postgresql as the database. Can you advice us regards to 'buffer' functions, which tools can we use for buffering? Should we use OpenLayers or Leaflet is 'good enough'?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The development version of OpenLayers has support for Web Processing Service (WPS).
See [this example](http://openlayers.org/dev/examples/wps-client.html).

You can use [GeoServer as a WPS server](http://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/extensions/wps/index.html). Use the JTS buffer operation to buffer your geometry.